# XmlNode.SelectNode with multiple attribute

Tags: c#, xml, selectnodes

One of my nodes inmy xml file is as follows.

```
  <LOGIN_ID NAME="Kapil">
    <SEARCH_ID>Kapil Koli</SEARCH_ID>
    <GUID>111</GUID>
    <FIRST_NAME>Kapil</FIRST_NAME>
    <LAST_NAME>Koli</LAST_NAME>
    <EMAIL_ID>kapil@abc.co.in</EMAIL_ID>
    <PASSWORD>abc123**</PASSWORD>
  </LOGIN_ID>
```

The code I am using is -

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(_XmlFileName);
nodeList = document.SelectNode."USERS/LOGIN_ID[contains(SEARCH_ID,'Kapil')";
nodeList = document.SelectNode."USERS/LOGIN_ID[contains(EMAIL_ID,'kapil@abc.co.in')";
```

I want to use select node which will accept search_id and login_id as attributes to search?
If either search_id or email_id is wrong, I want to return null.
How could I do this?

thanks.
kapil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
USERS/LOGIN_ID[contains(SEARCH_ID,'Kapil') and contains(EMAIL_ID,'kapil@abc.co.in')]
```

should do the trick.